# Avoiding overlapping plotly subplots in Shiny

Tags: shiny, plotly, overlap

I've been struggling to find the best way to avoid overlapping subplots. I tried autosize, where height is dependent on the number of rows but then the plotly graph overlaps with the proceeding widget (in this case a datatable) below it. The number of subplots changes based on user input.

Here's an image of what I get:[image]

```
plotly:: subplot(subplots, nrows = rows,titleY = TRUE) %>%
   layout(margin = list(b=200)) #,autosize=F, height=(300*rows))
```

Does anyone know how to render a plotly subplot that avoids these overlap issues?

Comment: Could you provide reproducible example?
As for overlapping other widgets, define height in your ui part of the plot, like plotOutput("YourPlot", height="550")

Comment: Thanks Asayat, yes I think that will be the best way to change the height rather than from the server side. Is it possible to pass a dynamic height dependent on number of subplots to the ui side? Maybe something like this would work... (will give it a go)

plotOutput("YourPlot", height=uiOutput("plotHeight"))

Comment: no that didn't work, I get an error:
Warning: Error in htmltools::validateCssUnit: CSS units must be a single-element numeric or character vector

Comment: could you provide some simple reproducible code as an example of what you up to? As for dynamics in ui part, check this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120696/shiny-plotoutput-dynamic-properties

Comment: thanks Asayat. I came up with a solution that works well when the size should change based on user inputs as you see in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I've found is to create a reactive where the plotly figure is constructed. The dynamically changing height should be based on user inputs. In my case, it was the number of processes and impact categories the user selectes to display in the figure so I came up with a relationship like height = 100*n_pro*n_imp. This height should be passed into plot_ly() (as well as the renderUI). The reactive is then called by a renderPlotly which is in turn called by a renderUI. In my case, I kept the width at 100% but that could also be updated. It would look as follows:

```
fig_creation = reactive({
      height = (something based on user input$)
      plot_ly(..., height = height)
)}

output$plotlyFig = renderPlotly({ fig_creation() })

output$figPlotly = renderUI({
        height = (something based on user input$) + 100 #the 100 is a buffer
        plotlyOutput("plotlyFig",width = "100%", height = paste0(height)
 })
```

On the UI side you simply use uiOutput("figPlotly"), where you want the figure to be placed.