# Why is plotOutput still brushable when it failed to validate?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a plot brushable, but there are scenarios when it is going to need to display a "not available" message, which I do with validate(need()). However, if the plot has shown up and then changes to invalid, the brush zone still exists (see picture). [image]

Minimum reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
   checkboxInput("Validate", label="Validate?", value=T),
  plotOutput("MainPlot", brush=brushOpts("MainPlotBrush", direction='x'))
)
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$MainPlot<-renderPlot({
     validate(need(input$Validate, message="This plot failed to render"))
     hist(rnorm(100))
   })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there a way to end the brush functionality when the plot is invalid?

Comment: The UI rendered with the brush regardless of what was produced in the server. You could move the plotOutput to the server to conditionally brush, then place the output as uiOutput or htmlOutput. Similar to an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120696/shiny-plotoutput-dynamic-properties

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Morton's suggestion provided a solution that removes the brush when invalid. You can validate in the renderUI instead of the renderPlot.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
   checkboxInput("Validate", label="Validate?", value=T),
  uiOutput("MainPlotSpot")
)
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$MainPlotSpot<-renderUI({
    validate(need(input$Validate, message="This plot failed to render"))
    plotOutput('MainPlot', brush=brushOpts("MainPlotBrush", direction='x'))
  })
   output$MainPlot<-renderPlot({
     hist(rnorm(100))
   })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```